# Не понимаю почему стили компонентов не видят глобальные переменные scss, но видят глобальны переменные css

Tags: reactjs, scss, next.js

```
.primary {
  color: var(--red); \\ её компонент next.js видит
  background-color: $primary; \\ её не видит
}
```

[[image: Ошибка выводится на скрине]

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Скорее всего потому что забыли импортировать файл, где объявлена SCSS переменная